# laravel get() return 2 rows but foreach gives only the last row()

Tags: laravel

- in order details table i have 2 row . When I use get() it gives 2 rows. But in foreach loop it only gives the last row.

**In Controller:**

```
$orderdetail = DB::table('order_details')->where('order_id',$eid)->get();

print_r($orderdetail);


$data =array();
foreach($orderdetail as $odetail){
    $data['id']                 = $odetail->product_id;
 }

dd($data);
```

**output:**

*following is the  output*

- Get() result:

  [0] (
  [id] => 832
  [product_id] => 1090
  )
  [1] (
  [id] => 833
  [product_id] => 1133
  )
- Foreach loop output

  array:1 [▼
  "id" => 1133
  ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You overwrite in $data['id'] in foreach loop ,so it has one member
,you can use one of this code:

```
$data =array();
foreach($orderdetail as $key=>$odetail){
    $data[$key]['id']= $odetail->product_id;
 }
dd($data);
```

OR

```
$data=DB::table('order_details')->where('order_id',$eid)->get()->pluck('product_id);
```

OR

```
$data =array();
$i=0
foreach($orderdetail as $odetail){
    $data[$i++]['id']= $odetail->product_id;
}
dd($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks  every one for your answer. I solved it following way:

```
foreach($orderdetail as $key=>$odetail){
    $data[$key]['id']= $odetail->product_id;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing array so its storing last data

```
$orderdetail = DB::table('order_details')->where('order_id',$eid)->get();

$data =[];
foreach($orderdetail as $odetail){
    $data[]= $odetail->product_id;
 }

dd($data);
```

if you need id as key then

```
$data =[]; 
foreach($orderdetail as $odetail){
   $data['id'][]= $odetail->product_id; 
}
```

or

```
$data[]['id']= $odetail->product_id;
```

or Simple way is to use pluck

```
$orderdetail = DB::table('order_details')->where('order_id',$eid)->pluck('product_id');
```